# The server of whois

Tags: dns, whois

Do you know a site or link which get together all the whois server of the domain. As these:

```
 'com'=>'whois.internic.net',
    'net'=>'whois.internic.net',
    'org'=>'whois.pir.org',
```

I am sorry, I don't need whois tool. I want to find resources and lists
 like these on wikipedia: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author and maintainer of the [Ruby whois library](https://whoisrb.org/).

You might want to have a look at the [library definition file](https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/master/data/tld.json). It contains the list of all existing TLDs as long as their corresponding WHOIS servers.

Comment: The link you provide isn't working any more.

Answer (score 0):

http://cqcounter.com/whois/

www.zoneedit.com/lookup.html

Is this what you want?

Comment: i am sorry, i don't need whois tool. i have updated my question

Comment: But. what's the difference between the sites you mentioned and a normal whois site?

Answer (score 0):

How about http://www.domaintools.com/ ?

Comment: i am sorry, i don't need whois tool. i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Whois servers list can be found:

http://www.nirsoft.net/whois_servers_list.html provides Whois servers in format:

- co whois.nic.co
- com whois.verisign-grs.com
- net whois.verisign-grs.com
- info whois.afilias.info

Or https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list/master/whois-server-list.xml provides XML structured format with extension, server, availability pattern and other information.